# iphone sdk 3.0, testing on firmware, not just simulator

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Testing an application built with iphone's sdk 3.0.  Based on experience, I know that bugs will manifest on hardware that will never appear in the simulator, so the simulator will only take me so far.  Is it possible to put the 3.0 beta firmware (not sdk) on a hardware device, and if so where can I find the beta firmware?  Or do I have to wait until mid-June for the release?

Comment: A definite yes on having joined the developer program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to be a member of the Apple Developer Network (free), and have a membership access to the iPhone Development (free for 2.x).

after you get your iPhone Developer license you will have access to the beta SDK's and the beta firmwares to the iPhone (I'm currently running 3.0 beta 5 on my iPhone 3G).

you can see what will you get if you have payed the 99 "bucks" for the iPhone Developer Program

[alt text http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5182/2042671054A1D7136B2BE0_m.png](http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5182/2042671054A1D7136B2BE0_m.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can download it on your Apple Developer page.

Comment: ...if you've paid the $99 to join the developer programme.

Comment: If you didn't, then you aren't allowed to use the beta OS anyway

Comment: If he's already developing with the iPhone 3 SDK, I assume he also has access to the beta firmware as well. And discussing the mere fact that people in the paid developer program can download these betas is probably not a violation of the NDA.